# kubuntu unkillable font management settings tool

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

Running kubuntu 16.04.1 fully up-to-date.

I brought up the font management tool (System Settings > Fonts > Font Management) and tried uninstalling a few fonts. The "Updating font configuration. Please wait..." progress bar was stuck at 100% for several minutes.

`sudo strace -f -p $(ps ax | grep fontinst | grep -v grep | cut -c 1-5)`  shows that it's stuck in a loop, lstat-ing a couple of hundred font files. It pauses for a few seconds, then stats the font directories and lstats a bunch of font files (see https://gist.github.com/jayeye/bb5ef45801c6b7ae1fbdea8917d7ad1f), and the process repeats.

If I kill the process, another one starts up doing the same. Neither the cancel button nor hitting x on the window frame kills it.

Help?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, no. Did it uninstall the fonts; perhaps it doesn't have permissions to delete them, attempts delete, fails, loops? Does `sudo kcmshell5 fontinst` work or get better output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this as well.  I don't know what causes it, but I usually just kill it with:

```
sudo kill -9 `pgrep systemsettings`
```